# Usefulness of prior PhD experience in USA PhD application

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

Suppose John is currently a first year PhD student applying to a US PhD program. I wonder if John's previous experience will be regarded as negative signal or a positive one in the eye of adcom.

Answer (score 0):

Absent other indicators, probably neutral. People change programs for lots of reasons, even if somewhat infrequently. But John will ned to provide any official transcript records for that year.

People successfully change programs even after a negative experience in their first go. In the US, lots of things are considered in the application process.